# How to merge two closer non straight(non parallel) lines in Python?

Tags: python, math, line

I have 2 lines drawn between two corners and want to merge them if these become closer to each other. but the problem is lines is not straight so if try to merge them the most closer corner is merging but another side is not. for example line1's and line2's end corners are in closer distance to each other but start corners are not.  Wonder your opinion guys. the code is below:

```
def mergeLineCorners(wallLines, _MERGE_TOLERANCE = 15):
for i in range(len(wallLines)):
    lineA = wallLines[i]
    for j in range(len(wallLines)):
        lineB = wallLines[j]
        if distance(lineA[0]['x'],lineA[0]['y'], lineB[0]['x'],lineB[0]['y']) < _MERGE_TOLERANCE: #A start B start 
            mid_x = float(lineA[0]['x'] + lineB[0]['x']) / 2
            mid_y = float(lineA[0]['y'] + lineB[0]['y']) / 2

            wallLines[i][0]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[i][0]['y'] = mid_y

            wallLines[j][0]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[j][0]['y'] = mid_y


        if distance(lineA[0]['x'],lineA[0]['y'], lineB[1]['x'], lineB[1]['y']) < _MERGE_TOLERANCE: #A start B end
            mid_x = float(lineA[0]['x'] + lineB[1]['x']) / 2
            mid_y = float(lineA[0]['y'] + lineB[1]['y']) / 2     

            wallLines[i][0]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[i][0]['y'] = mid_y
            wallLines[j][1]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[j][1]['y'] = mid_y
        if distance(lineA[1]['x'], lineA[1]['y'], lineB[0]['x'], lineB[0]['y']) < _MERGE_TOLERANCE:
            mid_x = float(lineA[1]['x'] + lineB[0]['x']) / 2
            mid_y = float(lineA[1]['y'] + lineB[0]['y']) / 2

            wallLines[i][1]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[i][1]['y'] = mid_y
            wallLines[j][0]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[j][0]['y'] = mid_y
        if distance(lineA[1]['x'], lineA[1]['y'], lineB[1]['x'], lineB[1]['y']) < _MERGE_TOLERANCE:
            mid_x = float(lineA[1]['x'] + lineB[1]['x']) / 2
            mid_y = float(lineA[1]['y'] + lineB[1]['y']) / 2

            wallLines[i][1]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[i][1]['y'] = mid_y
            wallLines[j][1]['x'] = mid_x
            wallLines[j][1]['y'] = mid_y

return wallLines
```

the corners incoming from JSON file and line xy position for example line 1. x: 330, y: 530. and line 2. x2: 330, y2: 570

left line is line1 right side is line2
[the output result after draw lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9csW.png)

As u see the end corners are merged but start points are not. because line2 is not straight as line1

Comment: Can you show an example case of non "straight" lines breaking your current algorithm?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog u can check the result url of screenshot. I get a some corners as JSON file and draw line between them.

Comment: Yes I've already seen that, and all I can see are straight lines. You need to clarify what you mean by "not straight".

Comment: @meowgoesthedog oh, i mean not straight lines are 1. x: 330, y: 530. and line 2. x2: 330, y2: 570. it means line1 is straight but line2 is not straight like line1 is | and line2 is /. and sorry Im not good in english, :-)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I upload another image, u can check

Comment: Both the lines in the image look straight. What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: @muze can you upload a better picture, may be bit zoomed out to see the problem.

Comment: @HåkenLid I meant as straight line: the line1's and line2's  end positions are in  closer distance to each other and start positions distance is not.

Comment: @hadik I upload again

Comment: maybe he means  straight == paralell?

Comment: @muze can you zoom out more. i dont know if your first line has a klink or not? Are they all straight line segment? I think you are not defining straight properly. You mean vertical instead of straight?

Comment: @muze again you can check out graphics algorithms : http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/ 

They have several similar problems and solutions.

Comment: @RobinNemeth oh thanks man u saved me .  i meant parallel

Comment: @hadik I meant lines arent parallel to each other. and thanks for url i will check it

Comment: @muze so what do you want as output when lines merge? you define lines as 2 points, and if they merge, you will have 1 line with 3 points.

Comment: @hadik I want to merge 2 line's end and start point as 1 line if they close to each other

Comment: so the result would be a mean of the two start points or how do you want to extrapolate your line?

Comment: also @muze you can make lines as `named tuples` or `class` , that might make your code more organized (but this is just a random suggestion)

Comment: @hadik the result should be merge two lines to one line. (merge star and end corners of lines to one.)